# run as administrator doesn't elevate process

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator, uac, netsh

I am trying to run `netsh wlan set hosted network mode=allow` as administrator but when I run it from an elevated cmd, or powershell, netsh still replies that:

```
You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator privilege.
```

I am positive that my cmd is elevated (ctrl+shift+enter or right click run as administrator), as it says so in the title bar, which starts with "Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" . Also, I can successfully run things like

```
echo "test-write-to-disk-in-admin-only-area" > c:\Windows\system32\test.txt
```

I tried to even start a cmd like this, and run netsh in it:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```

but netsh still believes it is not run as administrator.

For what it's worth, the computer is running a windows 7 in a corporate AD, but my user is an administrator for the PC I am working on.

Any ideas on how I could convince netsh that it is run as administrator? Or any thoughts of why netsh thinks it is not run as administrator?

Comment: Please try the commands in question using the built-in Administrator account or the SYSTEM account (using a tool like PSExec). It's possible your account does not have *all* of the administrative rights needed for the task you're trying to do. This step will confirm/refute this theory.

Comment: @Ramhound updated question, netsh wlan set hosted network mode=allow

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it is mentioned in the question, the computer is in a corporate AD. Perhaps the AD shortening was not clear enough that it stands for Active Directory. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

From a command-prompt, and from an elevated command prompt, run>

```
>whoami /groups
```

From a standard command prompt you should see:

```
Group Name             Type  SID          Attributes
====================== ===== ============ ========================
BUILTIN\Administrators Alias S-1-5-32-544 Group used for deny only
```

But from an elevated command prompt you should see:

```
Group Name             Type  SID          Attributes
====================== ===== ============ ===============================================================
BUILTIN\Administrators Alias S-1-5-32-544 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
```

## Check your privilege

After checking that you are a member of the Administrator's group (and not being denied it), check your privileges from an elevated command prompt:

```
>whoami /priv
```

Verify that you **have** all the privileges that an administrator should have:

```
Privilege Name                  Description                               State
=============================== ========================================= ========
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Disabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege           Load and unload device drivers            Disabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege        Profile system performance                Disabled
SeSystemtimePrivilege           Change the system time                    Disabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege Profile single process                    Disabled
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege Increase scheduling priority              Disabled
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege       Create a pagefile                         Disabled
SeBackupPrivilege               Back up files and directories             Disabled
SeRestorePrivilege              Restore files and directories             Disabled
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Disabled
SeDebugPrivilege                Debug programs                            Disabled
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege    Modify firmware environment values        Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege       Force shutdown from a remote system       Disabled
SeUndockPrivilege               Remove computer from docking station      Disabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege         Perform volume maintenance tasks          Disabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege          Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege         Create global objects                     Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege   Increase a process working set            Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege             Change the time zone                      Disabled
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege   Create symbolic links                     Disabled
```

**Note**: Even though a privilege may say **Disabled**, it means you still **have** it - it's just disabled. Contrast that with a standard user from a non-elevated command prompt:

```
Privilege Name                Description                          State
============================= ==================================== ========
SeShutdownPrivilege           Shut down the system                 Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Bypass traverse checking             Enabled
SeUndockPrivilege             Remove computer from docking station Disabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Increase a process working set       Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege           Change the time zone                 Disabled
```

Standard users simply don't **have** the privileges of an Administrator.

Once you're running an elevated command prompt, and you can see you have the identity, all the the privileges of an Administrator, run `netsh`:

Answer (score -1):

If we do this manually, instead of using the command to perform this operation, can it be successfully executed?

If not, I think because this is a domain-joined computer, this command creates a shared wireless network for this domain-joined computer, so this operation should be limited by the domain policy, even if we ran this command as an administrator, but could not successfully execute this command.